# Citing and Tag wiki

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

Is citing required for Tag wikis that come from other sources? If so, how does one do it? I am just curious as there is plenty of info out there and if something is a direct quote, should it be cited?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tag wiki content should be cited just as you would if you were posting it as an answer. You'd quote a few sentences with a link back to the source.

If you need to quote more than three sentences, that's already too much. (Three is just a rule of thumb and pinkie.)

Better no more than that and just fill out the rest of the tag wiki with more Super User specific information such as related tags, top list of questions, how best to use the tag on a question, etc.

Comment: While I generally agree with the three sentence rule, there are times that I've copied content from software product info pages for new/empty tag wiki's.  I feel like this is acceptable if done in moderation.

Comment: Moderation meaning rarely. When a user is at SU, they should already know what the product is they're tagging with. We don't need to be pitching sales

Comment: Again, in general I would agree, but there are times that individuals that are editing the tag wikis aren't the ones that created them in the first place nor they may not know a lot about the tags.